# safari wont load windows authentication on a spesific network

Tags: macos, safari, windows-authentication

I have an Intranet Web Application which uses Windows Authentication. All windows/PC users can login in fine.

There happen to be 2 Mac Users that use Safari as their default browser and prefer it over chrome for Mac.

When trying to access the Intranet Web Application on the network, nothing happens. But when trying to access the Intranet Web Application from another network or source of internet outside the network, the user is able to login.

Is there something I have missed? Any thoughts on this please.

Converting them to Chrome is the last option in this option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this, the answer was simple. In IIS under the Authentication. Setting the providers. I removed Negotiate and kept NTLM. Apple seems to accept this security method.